# How to know which namespaces to refer in XBRL instance

Tags: xml, xbrl

I am new to XBRL and am trying to learn it. In an XBRL instance I saw several namespaces referred at the top of the document; eg. xmlns:xbrli, xmlns:xbrldt, xmlns:xbrldi etc. However not all are used in the instance document; i.e. there are no nodes that begin with 
xbrldi:myNode ...

Is it ok to remove the unused namespace references? Also, I would like to know where I can find the URLs for the namespaces. I found the URLs for a few of them in the linkbases, but others like xmlns:iso4217 i cant find. Where do the URLs come from?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The namespaces are defined within the XBRL Specification, available [here](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html). Section 1.6 of the specification offers the following list:

- link: http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase
- xbrli: http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance
- xl: http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink
- xlink: http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
- xml: http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
- xsi: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
- xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Other namespaces are defined throughout the document. The ISO4217 namespace is shown in Section 4.8.4 as http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217.